# Параллельное создание объектов класса

Tags: qt, многопоточность, классы, qt5

Есть класс. Как сделать параллельное создание экземпляров класса? Т.е. в конструкторе этого класса довольно емкая логика. Хочу создать отдельные потоки для каждого экземпляра, затем запустить их вместе не зависимо друг от друга, и дождаться выполнения всех потоков.

Comment: пример с использованием C++11 подойдёт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
concurrency::task<A*> task1([=](){ return new A(); });
concurrency::task<A*> task2([=](){ return new A(); });
(task1 && task2).wait();
A* obj1 = task1.get();
A* obj2 = task2.get();
```

или так:

```
std::future<A*> f1 = std::async([=](){ return new A(); });
std::future<A*> f2 = std::async([=](){ return new A(); });
f1.wait();
f2.wait();
A* obj1 = f1.get();
A* obj2 = f2.get();
```

Comment: Не думаю что C++ 11 код чем-то поможет мне в Qt :(

Comment: @ОлегС, Код компилируется и в Qt (проверил на Qt 5.3.2 c компилятором от MSVC2013). Получившийся код будет кроссплатформенным, если именно это вас беспокоит.

Comment: Мне также кажется, что Вам ответили ровно на поставленный вопрос. Для кошерности, все таки у Вас Qt5, можете использовать [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html)
Другое дело, что архитектурно странны тяжелые конструкторы.